# How to calculate d/dx[du/dt] in NN w.r.t inputs (x,t) in Keras/Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Lets say I have the following neural network with two inputs:

(x, t) ---> [neural network] ---> u(x,t)

I need to calculate du(x,t)/dx, du(x,t)/dt, and most importantly the partial d/dx[du(x,t)/dt]

I managed to create this code that runs without errors but the derivatives are None. Anyone can help please?

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=" "
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']="3"
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

print("TensorFlow version: {}".format(tf.__version__))
print("Eager execution: {}".format(tf.executing_eagerly()))

class ODENetwork():

    def __init__(self):
        self.model = None

    def get_data(self):
        x_state = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, num=10)
        t_state = np.linspace(0.0, 1, num=100)
        x, t = np.meshgrid(x_state, t_state)
        x_train = np.column_stack((x.ravel(), t.ravel()))
        return x_train 

    def fit(self):
        inputs = keras.Input(shape=(2,))
        l1 = layers.Dense(20, activation="sigmoid")(inputs)
        outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(l1)
        self.model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="experimental")
        return self

    def train(self):
        epochs = 2
        optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch, ))

            for step, (x, t) in enumerate(self.get_data()):
                x = tf.Variable(x)
                t = tf.Variable(t)

                with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

                    with tape.stop_recording():
                        tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[x, t]]), dtype=tf.float32)
                        u = self.model(tensor, training=True)

                grad = tape.gradient(u, {'x': x, 't': t})
                print('du/dx:', grad['x'])
                print('du/dt:', grad['t'])
                print('d/dx[du/dt:') # <-- ???

def main():

    ode_net = ODENetwork().fit()
    ode_net.train()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Update** - I figured it out

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch, ))

    for step, (x, t) in enumerate(self.get_data()):

        x = tf.constant(x)
        t = tf.constant(t)

        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape_ord_2:
            tape_ord_2.watch((x, t))

            with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape_ord_1:
                tape_ord_1.watch((x, t))
                tensor_data = tf.cast([[x, t]], tf.float32)
                u = self.model(tensor_data, training=True)

            u_x = tape_ord_1.gradient(u, x)
            u_t = tape_ord_1.gradient(u, t)
        u_xx = tape_ord_2.gradient(u_x, x)
        u_tt = tape_ord_2.gradient(u_t, t)

        u_xt = tape_ord_2.gradient(u_x, t)
        u_tx = tape_ord_2.gradient(u_t, x)

        # these should be the same, and they are
        print('u_xt: {},  u_tx: {}'.format(u_xt, u_tx))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you EdvBeq for the update. For the benefit of community providing solution here.

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=" "
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']="3"
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

print("TensorFlow version: {}".format(tf.__version__))
print("Eager execution: {}".format(tf.executing_eagerly()))

class ODENetwork():

    def __init__(self):
        self.model = None

    def get_data(self):
        x_state = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, num=10)
        t_state = np.linspace(0.0, 1, num=100)
        x, t = np.meshgrid(x_state, t_state)
        x_train = np.column_stack((x.ravel(), t.ravel()))
        return x_train 

    def fit(self):
        inputs = keras.Input(shape=(2,))
        l1 = layers.Dense(20, activation="sigmoid")(inputs)
        outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(l1)
        self.model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="experimental")
        return self

    def train(self):
        epochs = 2
        optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)

        for epoch in range(epochs):
          print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch, ))

          for step, (x, t) in enumerate(self.get_data()):

           x = tf.constant(x)
           t = tf.constant(t)

           with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape_ord_2:

             tape_ord_2.watch((x, t))

             with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape_ord_1:


               tape_ord_1.watch((x, t))
               tensor_data = tf.cast([[x, t]], tf.float32)
               u = self.model(tensor_data, training=True)

             u_x = tape_ord_1.gradient(u, x)
             u_t = tape_ord_1.gradient(u, t)
          u_xx = tape_ord_2.gradient(u_x, x)
          u_tt = tape_ord_2.gradient(u_t, t)

          u_xt = tape_ord_2.gradient(u_x, t)
          u_tx = tape_ord_2.gradient(u_t, x)

          # these should be the same, and they are
          print('u_xt: {},  u_tx: {}'.format(u_xt, u_tx))

def main():

    ode_net = ODENetwork().fit()
    ode_net.train()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
TensorFlow version: 2.4.1
Eager execution: True

Start of epoch 0
u_xt: 0.004451256711035967,  u_tx: 0.0044512562453746796

Start of epoch 1
u_xt: 0.004451256711035967,  u_tx: 0.0044512562453746796
```